# AOSP Build error: EXECUTABLES/iw_intermediates/version.c

Tags: android, android-source, custom-rom

I've made a AOSP build 7.1.1 couple of days ago and it works well. Today I decided to make a clean build (`make clean`) and start working on it. After that when I'm trying to compile by `make otapackage` after some time it gives me below error.

```
[ 44% 7552/17136] build out/target/product/hikari/gen/EXECUTABLES/iw_intermediates/version.c
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "external/iw/version.sh out/target/product/hikari/gen/EXECUTABLES/iw_intermediates/version.c"
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:148: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (01:39:34 (hh:mm:ss)) ####
```

Everytime, its the same. Any solution ?

Answer (score 3):

Its failing when it is trying to check the git version number.
Inside external/iw/version.sh, it is failing when it gets to:

> descr=$(git describe --match=v*):

```
if [ -d .git ] && head=`git rev-parse --verify HEAD 2>/dev/null`; then
        git update-index --refresh --unmerged > /dev/null
        descr=$(git describe --match=v*)
        # on git builds check that the version number above                                     
        # is correct...                                                                         
        [ "${descr%%-*}" = "v$VERSION" ] || exit 2

        v="${descr#v}"
        if git diff-index --name-only HEAD | read dummy ; then
                v="$v"-dirty
        fi
else
        v="$VERSION"
fi
echo '#include "iw.h"' > "$OUT"
echo "const char iw_version[] = \"$v\";" >> "$OUT"
```

I had the same problem and there is two ways to go about it:

> 1. You can comment out everything except v="$VERSION" and the last two
>      echo lines.But this is a temporary fix.
> 2. Another way to solve this is by doing a repo sync before you execute make. I fixed it by simply doing a repo sync and that updated and
>      fixed everything for me.